# Good practice for multilingual html SCORM content

Tags: javascript, html, multilingual, scorm

This is more a "theoretical" question rather a technical one.

I need to create SCORM e-learning content, pure HTML-CSS-Javascript without any server side technology and this content must be multilingual. Two main requirements: multilingual, not server side languajes.

And my question is what is the best way to achieve this? These are the obvious options:

1. Duplicate html files in the needed languages in different folders for each languaje.
2. Load all language files (i. ex in xml or json), parse the html dom
   and asign the content dinamically with javascript.

In the second case, loading files dinamically, what would be a good way of doing it? I would dislike somethink like this because all the obstrusive script tags within the html:

```
<div>
<p><script> document.write(some_translatable_variable) </script></p>
</div>
```

And also I dislike something like the following because it would require a lot of ids and it's really dificult to maintain:

```
//in json file lang.es.json
"some_translatable_variable" : "Esto está en español";

//In a loaded langs.js, using jquery:
$("#some_id").html("<p>"+some_translatable_variable+"<p>");


//the html code
<div id="some_id"> <!-- nothing here --> </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a JavaScript-based templating engine such as [Mustache](http://mustache.github.io/), [Handlebars](http://handlebarsjs.com/), or [Angular](http://angularjs.org/).

Basically you'd put a placeholder in your HTML, and the JavaScript would replace the placeholder with your text. You don't need to manage a slew of IDs.

You can insert text from a different language if desired, just be sure to watch out for layout issues, such as RTL languages and very long sentences that might break your layout.

Here are some helpful articles about client-side templates:
http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2012/12/05/client-side-templating/
http://engineering.linkedin.com/frontend/client-side-templating-throwdown-mustache-handlebars-dustjs-and-more
http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/best-practices-when-working-with-javascript-templates/